# Firebird database performance after server upgrade/restart

Tags: performance, firebird

Got a 350 GB database (more than 40M records plus 0 - 1000 BLOBs for each record in another table). After upgrading Firebird to version 2.1.5 (mainly because of [filesystem cache issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/302172/high-memory-utilization-with-firebird-windows-server-2008-r2/374317#374317)) database became terribly slow, both insertion and fetching. How to restore performance? I tried running some queries to force caching, it was somewhat helpful, and currently left it with `gbak` running, but what's the"proper" way?

**UPDATE:**
Everything went back to normal in 24 hours or so, but the question is still relevant.

Comment: Probably should stick to 2.1.3 - it wasn't that bad after all, since they were able to store and query all that data :)

Comment: Did you by any chance upgrade from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Comment: Nope, 32 bit in both cases.